# CapybaraとPoltergeistを使用した場合にDBの内容がビューに反映されない

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

Poltergeistを使用した場合、Capybaraのテストケースの挙動が不思議です。

まず最初に、Poltergeistを使用しない場合、Capybaraのテストケースはsuccessです。

```
before { create(:user) }
it 'test' do
  visit root_path
  expect(page).to have_content 'ユーザは1人です'
end
```

テスト対象のviewでは

ユーザは`<%= User.count %>`人です

のような記述です。
JSのテストを行いたいため、

```
it 'test', js: true do
```

とすると、表示が「ユーザは0人です」のようになり、テストがfailureとなります。
(page.save_screenshotにて確認)

どうやらbeforeで作成したユーザがうまくviewで取得できてないようです。

```
expect(User.count).to eq 1
```

はsuccessなので、DBに書き込みは行われています。

Poltergeistの代わりにcapybara-webkitでも同じ状況です。
どうすればテストを通すことができるでしょうか？

Comment: タイトルだけでも問題を把握できるように (質問一覧で目にとまりやすいように)、また最後の一文を解決したい内容で締めるように (何を答えればよいかが分かりやすいように) 編集しました。元々の意図と違ってしまっているところなどあれば、お手数ですが[edit]して上書きしてしまってください。

Answer (score 4):

僕が翻訳した「[Everyday Rails - RSpecによるRailsテスト入門](https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec-jp/)」という電子書籍で、サンプルアプリケーションのソースコードがGitHubに公開されています。
使用しているのはPoltergeistではなくselenium-webdriverなのですが、考え方は同じなのでコード例を載せておきます。

https://github.com/everydayrails/rails-4-1-rspec-3-0/blob/master/spec/rails_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # ...
end
```

`use_transactional_fixtures` は `true` に設定していますが、 `false` または設定をコメントアウト（デフォルトが`false`）に設定しても問題ありませんでした。

また、`DatabaseCleaner.cleaning`はバージョン1.3.0から導入されたので、必要に応じてDatabaseCleanerをアップデートしてください。

https://github.com/everydayrails/rails-4-1-rspec-3-0/blob/master/Gemfile

```
group :test do
  # ...
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 1.3.0"
  # ...
end
```

設定の意味は「[Everyday Rails - RSpecによるRailsテスト入門](https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec-jp/)」に載っているので抜粋しておきます。

> これは何をやっているのでしょうか？最初にやっているのはテストデータをセットアップする際に使う 戦略（strategy）の指定です。それぞれのテストを独立させた状態にするため、ここでは トランザクション（transaction）を指定しました。ご想像の通り、これはデータベースのトランザクションを使う戦略です。続いて、データを全件削除（clean）するためにテーブルのトランケート（truncation）を指定しています。最後に、トランザクションの開始と終了を実行するタイミングと（これはテストスイート中の各exampleを実行する前後です）、全件削除を実行するタイミング（これは各exampleを実行した後です）を指定しています。

あともう一点、 `spec/support/shared_db_connection.rb`というファイルを作成し、以下の内容を記述してください。

https://github.com/everydayrails/rails-4-1-rspec-3-0/blob/master/spec/support/shared_db_connection.rb

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :shared_connection
  @@shared_connection = nil

  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

この設定の必要性についても書籍の中で述べられています。

> なぜこのような変更が必要になるのでしょうか？端的に答えるのであれば、Seleniumを使った場合、データベーストランザクションの扱い方に違いが出てくるからです。テストを実行するときはSelenium webサーバとテストコードの双方でデータの状態を共有しなければいけません。DatabaseCleanerと上記のパッチがないと、テスト実行後のクリーンアップが正しく行われないために、テストが時折失敗する可能性があります。

Everyday Railsには他にもRailsのテストに関する実践的な内容が載っているので、困ったときのリファレンス本として役立ちます。もしよかったら読んでみてください。

[Everyday Rails - RSpecによるRailsテスト入門](https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec-jp/)

Comment: 正に
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
でうまくいきました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

RSpecの設定で`use_transactional_fixtures`が`true`に設定されていませんか?

> What it really means in Rails is "run every test method within a transaction."

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions

この設定が`true`になっている場合、すべてのテストはトランザクション中で実行されます。
なので、`create(:user)`もトランザクション中で実行されます。
Capybaraで`visit root_path`しても、`create(:user)`のトランザクションはコミットされていないため、レコードが作成されておらず、0人と表示されます。

`use_transactional_fixtures`を`false`にするとテストは通るようになると思います。

ただし、その場合はテストで作成したレコードを削除するなどの処理を自分で管理する必要があるため、
[database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner)や[database_rewinder](https://github.com/amatsuda/database_rewinder)などのgemを合わせてつかい、テストで作成したレコードをロールバックさせるように設定するとよいと思います。

Comment: 今回database_rewinderを使っていますが
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
でうまくいきまいした。
ありがとうございます。